# JS confirm is not working on my PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

What im trying to do is an "item search window". When the user start searching for an item and it is not found an alert pop op saying that the item does not exist, then another pop comes out and ask the user if he want to insert that item in the data base.

The following code is my attempt to get that work but when it runs my `confirm` simply don't  show up and my code continues running the `If` acctions.

What im i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help and comments.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The item '.$_POST{'item'}.' does not exist");</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">if(confirm("Do you want to insert it?") == "true"){</script>';

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("If this show up the confirm does not work");</script>';
            echo '<style type="text/css">.DivInvisible {display: initial;}</style>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        }
        </script>';
```

Comment: remove the double-quotes around "true". You should be checking for true/false boolean and not string "true".

Comment: Still getting the same result. Previously I got my 'confirm' as 'if(confirm("Do you want to insert it?"))' and it works in other section of my code

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the script tags on each row? That wont work. You can't open a if statement in one tag and close it in another. Have one `<script>`, put all your JS in it and add a `</script>` _after_ all the code. You should really check your console. There should be some errors in there.

Comment: But how can I make JS change my css class? I did that thing in my IF because i tried to put the PHP echo on it. But as you said... It did not work

Comment: You don't add css like that. You make css classes, which you include in the file. Then you can add/remove what css classes an element has, using JS.